# Draw graph for each of the relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Its image about my question which I want to solve but I have no idea how to solve it. Draw graph for each relation and say whether relation is a function or not.

[image]

Please make me understand how to solve this question.

Comment: A relation $xRy$ being a function means that, for any $x$, there is one and only one $y$ that satisfies the relation. It's not a function if one $x$ has several $y$'s related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a vertex for each element in your set (*in your case a vertex representing each of the cities*).

Then, for whichever specific relation you are looking at, draw an arrow (*called a directed edge*) from one vertex $x$ to another vertex $y$ if and only if $x$ is related to $y$.  If it so happens that $x$ is related to $y$ *and* $y$ is related to $x$, you may either make the arrow double sided, or draw a separate arrow going in the opposite direction in addition to the first according to your personal preference.  If an element is related to itself, draw a directed "loop" for the corresponding vertex, a curved arrow which leaves the vertex and turns around and points at the same vertex.

Such a graph represents a function iff every vertex has *exactly one* arrow *leaving* it.  Similar properties of relations and functions can also be described from a graph theoritic point of view (*for example, bijective functions from a set to itself have exactly one arrow *leaving* and exactly one arrow *arriving* at each vertex*)